# Deadlock in MariaDB when inserting/deleting in highly concurrent environment

Tags: mariadb, deadlock

In our highly concurrent web application productive environment we have detected MariaDB prohibits some deadlocks and we had to react to this.

Our DB schema is quite huge and complicated, but I managed to reduce and reproduce this problem with simple DB schema consisting of only one table with two columns.

```
create table test_entity (
    id bigint,
    last_changed datetime(6)
);
```

(All insert/update/delete queries below are wrapped in transaction)

The deadlock happens when there are multiple clients calling API to insert into this table with simple:

```
insert into test_entity(N, someDate);
```

While server randomly calls wipe process for entities older than date T1.

```
delete from test_entity where last_changed < T1;
```

By simply combining these two commands it could happen that MariaDB starts prohibiting deadlocks for both inserts and delete queries.

Indexing column "test_entity.last_changed" did not resolve this problem.

The solution that started working well is if delete logic isn't directly calling delete query over column "last_changed", but works as:

```
-- Store IDs from select query below in memory into variable $IDS_TO_DELETE
-- Either all of them at once, or chunks of N by adding "limit N" to the select query
select id from test_entity where changed_at < T1;
delete from test_entity where id in $IDS_TO_DELETE;
```

This solution seems to be less performant - though acceptable for our scale of application.

What is the "behind the curtains" problem causing the deadlock in first solution?
Is it normal it is reproducible by such simple table?

Comment: Is there a primary key on `id`? "deadlock" is aquiring two locks in a different order to another transaction. What are the transactions involving more than one SQL statement? Or do you mean "lock wait" instead of deadlock? [`tx_isolation=READ-COMMITTED`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#tx_isolation) maybe?

Comment: Can you avoid using a `T1` that is greater than the largest `last_changed`?  And can you avoid inserting a `someDate` greater than the largest `last_changed`?  Or think of a better schema for purging the table.